# Black bar showing up above keyboard when typing password

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

In some cases, when I lift up a keyboard, I see this:

[image]

[image]

but on different devices, I get this:

Why is this happening?

Here is the code I use for keyboard handling:

```
  //MARK: Keyboard handling

    private func registerKeyboardNotifications(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }


    @objc func keyboardDidShow(notification:NSNotification){
        isKeyboardVisible = true

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {


            print("Keyboard size \(keyboardSize)")
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardDidHide(notification:NSNotification){
        isKeyboardVisible = false


        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {



        }
    }
```

My textfield has secureTextEntry property set to true.

Comment: on which devices you get this issue ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri That is the info I am waiting from my QA. But, I would say iPhone X according to a full pic.Also it works for me on iPhone 6 and 6s with iOS12 installed.